# GoogleTest only work when definition is in .h file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, googletest

I have spend all day trying to make GoogleTest work in Visual Studio 2013. Finally, made it to "work", but it only works when definition of the function is place in the .h file. Using separate compilation, such as =:

```
// simplemath.h
#include <cmath>
double cubic(double d);

// simple.cpp
#include "simplemath.h"
double cubic(double d)
{
    return pow(d, 3);
}

// unittest_SimpleMath.cpp
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "simplemath.h"    
TEST(testMath, myCubeTest)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(1000, cubic(10));
}
```

produces the following error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: unittest_SimpleMath, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>  unittest_SimpleMath.cpp
1>unittest_SimpleMath.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "double __cdecl cubic(double)" (?cubic@@YANN@Z)
1>C:\Users\alex\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\SimpleMath\Release\unittest_SimpleMath.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 2 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Edit: Forgot to mention one important thing. I followed tutorial http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/google_unit_test_gtest.php to figure out how to pair-up Gtest and VS2013. My solution structure is identical to what is desc. in the tutorial - 3 projects.

Comment: you need to link the object files (no idea how it is done for vs)

Comment: Check this discussion on VS 2013 and gtest https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/googletestframework/-kiysbIugGw

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using different project for the tests. You should either use tests in the same project you have your `cubic` function. Or make lib from your `cubic` code and link it in the tests project. The errors you have aren't connected to gtest in any way. You just  have not compiled your cpp file to an object file which could be used in the tests project.

Also, make sure you have `gtest_main*.lib`(asterisk there because it has a few name, you should choose whatever you need) linked in your test project since you don't have `main` for it(or you didn't show it).

Comment: See the edit in my question. Indeed, I am using 3 different projects for the solution: Main Project, Google Test Project compiled into static library, and Unit Test project. Could you elaborate on one of the methods you have described. My goal is to have Main project and Unit Test project as separate projects.Thanks!

Comment: For this to be done you should have your SimpleMath project to output library which you will link at your test project and test it. Another way is to add all your cpp files to both projects(bad way). But you can't just create 2 different projects and use one function from another if it is defined in cpp file. Each cpp file generates `obj` file after compilation which is used during linking. One project doesn't see obj files of other project